# splitting a string into positive and negative number python?

Tags: python, string, split

I want to be able to split something like this:

```
"20 - 5 - 4 + 10 + 4"
```

either into one list as signed numbers:

```
["20", "-5", "-4", "+10", "+4"]
```

or into two list as unsigned:

```
["20", "10", "4"]
["5", "4"]
```

is there a built in method i can use to do this in python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "20 - 5 - 4 + 10 + 4"
new_s = re.findall('[-+]?\d+', s.replace(' ', ''))
```

Output:

```
['20', '-5', '-4', '+10', '+4']
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `re.findall('[-+]?\d+', s.replace(' ', ''))`. Also it's a good habit to always use raw strings here.

Answer (score 0):

Without `regex` but would break if no spaces or any other operator is present.

```
expr = "20 - 5 - 4 + 10 + 4"
tokens = expr.split()
if tokens[0].isnumeric():tokens = ['+'] + tokens
tokens = [''.join(t) for t in zip(*[iter(tokens)]*2)]
pos = [t.strip('+') for t in tokens if '+' in t]
neg = [t.strip('-') for t in tokens if '-' in t]
```

Or as `@Sayse` suggested:

```
tokens = expr.replace('- ','-').replace('+ ','+').split()
pos = [t.strip('+') for t in tokens if '-' not in t]
neg = [t.strip('-') for t in tokens if '-' in t]
```